# How to Easily Pass an Environment Variable to an .exe in "Bash on Windows 10"?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, windows-10, environment-variables

I am looking for a way to easily pass an environment variable to a .exe when invoked from the Bash on Windows 10 terminal. It seems that

```
TEST=somevalue example.exe
```

does not work.

Comment: When you say "Bash", do you mean the Windows command prompt? (it might look like Bash, but it's not quite the same)

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt Windows 10 has a ['Bash on Windows'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) where you can run Linux command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the command above doesn't work is because it's a *Linux* environment variable you're setting. In "normal" Windows `cmd.exe`, you'd be able to start with `set TEST=somevalue` but this doesn't appear to work in `bash.exe`, the Linux environment variable is not shared with the Windows executable (the call to `set` is actually to the set command in `bash` itself).

So, if you're looking for a workaround, I can think of a two-step way to accomplish this. First, call the command in the context of `cmd.exe` instead of `bash.exe`, which you can do with the `/C` parameter. Second, you'd need to actually be able to do this in a oneliner in `cmd.exe`, which also requires a workaround, because doing `set FOO="bar" & echo %FOO%` does not work in `cmd.exe` (try it). If you prepend the `echo` command with `call` it does. This results in the following full command:

`cmd.exe /C "set FOO=\"bar\" & call echo %FOO%"`

You'll see that this results in the output `"bar"`.